# Print a list of every combination of dictionary keys with the associated sum of the key values to the right

Tags: python, dictionary, product, python-itertools, cartesian-product

I have several dictionaries and I want to print a table where each row is a unique combination of the keys in all dictionaries.  For each row, I also want to print the sum of the values for the keys in that particular combination.

So, if I have these dictionaries:

```
dict1 = {"Main": 8, "Optional": 6, "Obscure": 4}
dict2 = {"Global": 8, "Regional": 4, "Local": 2}
...
```

The output would look like this (sorted by sum highest to lowest):

```
Main, Global, 16
Optional, Global, 14
Main, Regional, 12
Obscure, Global, 12
Main, Local, 10
Optional, Regional, 10
Optional, Local, 8
Obscure, Regional, 8
Obscure, Local, 6
```

From what I've read, itertools.product will be what I'm looking for, but none of the existing questions are quite my use case and I'm struggling to even get started.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've read right. Just add `sorted()`:

```
from itertools import product
from operator import itemgetter

results = [(k1, k2, dict1[k1] + dict2[k2])
           for k1, k2 in product(dict1.keys(), dict2.keys())]

for k1, k2, sum_ in sorted(results, key=itemgetter(2), reverse=True): 
    print(k1, k2, sum_, sep=', ')
```

Comment: This worked perfectly!  I have a lot of dictionaries, so I had to add extra variables and adjust the itemgetter values, but otherwise perfect.  Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this would be something like:

```
import itertools

dict1 = {"Main": 8, "Optional": 6, "Obscure": 4}
dict2 = {"Global": 8, "Regional": 4, "Local": 2}

merged = {'{}, {}'.format(prod[0], prod[1]): dict1[prod[0]] + dict2[prod[1]] 
          for prod in itertools.product(dict1, dict2)}

for k, v in merged.items():
    print('{}: {}'.format(k, v))
```

Output:

```
Optional, Regional: 10
Main, Regional: 12
Optional, Local: 8
Main, Global: 16
Optional, Global: 14
Main, Local: 10
Obscure, Regional: 8
Obscure, Global: 12
Obscure, Local: 6
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `product` from `itertools` on the dictionary items() where you can get the both key and value at the same time, and with the combination of key-value pairs you can construct the final result pretty straightforwardly:

```
from itertools import product
sorted([(k1, k2, v1+v2) for (k1, v1), (k2, v2) in product(dict1.items(), dict2.items())], \
       key = lambda x: x[2], reverse=True)

# [('Main', 'Global', 16),
#  ('Optional', 'Global', 14),
#  ('Obscure', 'Global', 12),
#  ('Main', 'Regional', 12),
#  ('Main', 'Local', 10),
#  ('Optional', 'Regional', 10),
#  ('Obscure', 'Regional', 8),
#  ('Optional', 'Local', 8),
#  ('Obscure', 'Local', 6)]
```

Comment: This answer is more efficient than the others posted so far since it avoids unnecessary `dict` lookups by using `.items()` (though you should use `.viewitems()` on Py2 to minimize temporary `list`s) and unnecessary `tuple` indexing by using unpacking to named variables. Needs to add the sorting step though (`operator.itemgetter(2)` for the `key` function).

Comment: @ShadowRanger though true, the difference is somewhat minimal (2.29µs vs. 2.33µs for example, py3). But using `items()` and unpacking is a nice touch.

Answer (score 0):

This method is built to support a variable amount of dictionaries. You pass your dictionaries to the `get_product_sums()` method, which then creates a cartesian product from the tuple of dictionaries.

We then iterate through our new `subitem` to calculate sums by doing a look up in our `flattened` which is just a 1D dictionary now. We then sort by the sum, and return a sorted list of tuples for our final `result`.

```
from itertools import product

def get_product_sums(* args):
    result = []
    flattened = {k:v for d in args for k, v in d.items()}
    for subitem in product(* args, repeat=1):
        data = subitem + (sum(flattened[key] for key in subitem),)  
        result.append(data)
    return sorted(result, key=lambda x: x[-1], reverse=True)
```

**Sample Output:**

```
>>> dict1 = {"Global": 8, "Regional": 4, "Local": 2} 
>>> dict2 = {"Main": 8, "Optional": 6, "Obscure": 4}
>>> for item in get_product_sums(dict1, dict2):
...     print ', '.join(str(element) for element in item)
Global, Main, 16
Global, Optional, 14
Global, Obscure, 12
Regional, Main, 12
Local, Main, 10
Regional, Optional, 10
Local, Optional, 8
Regional, Obscure, 8
Local, Obscure, 6
```

Comment: *args can be used instead of a tuple of dictionaries

Comment: @DiegoAllen For sure! I left it as a tuple because I'm not sure in which way he handles data.